# Look up a number inside a list within a pandas cell, and return corresponding string value from a second DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

(I've edited the first column name in the labels_df for clarity)

I have two DataFrames, train_df and labels_df.  train_df has integers that map to attribute names in the labels_df.  I would like to look up each number within a given train_df cell and return in the adjacent cell, the corresponding attribute name from the labels_df.

So fore example, the first observation in train_df has attribute_ids of 147, 616 and 813 which map to (in the labels_df) culture::french, tag::dogs, tag::men.  And I would like to place those strings inside one cell on the same row as the corresponding integers.

[image]

I've tried variations of the function below but fear I am wayyy off:

```
def my_mapping(df1, df2):
    tags = df1['attribute_ids']
    for i in tags.iteritems():
        df1['new_col'] = df2.iloc[i]
    return df1
```

The data are originally from two csv files:

train.csv

[image]

labels.csv

[image]

I tried this from @Danny :

```
sample_train_df['attribute_ids'].apply(lambda x: [sample_labels_df[sample_labels_df['attribute_name'] == i]
                                              ['attribute_id_num'] for i in x])
```

*please note - I am running the above code on samples of each DF due to run times on the original DFs.
which returned:

[image]

Comment: You should add a sample of the two dataframes, so we can understand how your data are organized. As text, not as images.

Comment: @Valentino, I am not clear on your suggestion.  The original data are in two csv files.  Would a sample of those help?

Comment: Yes, indeed. If we don't see the original data, is impossible to provide a solution based on them. You can copy-paste few meaningful lines from each csv in your question.

Comment: @Valentino , okay, thank you.  I've updated the post.  I didn't think that mattered since i'm working with them in pandas now.  I did try to complete my goal in the csv files with vlookup , text to columns, concat... but the formatting of train.csv [id] breaks somehow and will not work in the algorithm for my neural net.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. i am sure there's a much more efficient way using look up.

`df['new_col'] = df['attribute_ids'].apply(lambda x: [labels_df[labels_df['attribute_id'] == i]['attribute_name'] for i in x])`

Comment: Thanks @Danny, I got syntax errors and moved around some brackets and am now getting a KeyError.  I will edit the origianal post so I can past the entire traceback.

Comment: Your brackets are not consistent with the code I have pasted. Please check and let me know again. `labels_df[labels_df['attribute_name'] == i]['attribute_id']` It should be like this.

Comment: Please mark it as answered if this answered your question.

Comment: thanks @Danny, I've updated the OP with the new output.

Comment: Could you post your dataframes?

Comment: hey, @Danny, I've updated to include the original dataframes.  Since they are so large and taking a long time to run code on, i've changed your code to run off sub samples.  I also changed the name of labels_df[attribute_id] to attribute_id_num, for clarity.

Comment: Are you not supposed to get the names with IDs? The code that you used in the question with my help does the opposite.

Comment: So fore example, the first observation in train_df has attribute_ids of 147, 616 and 813 which map to (in the labels_df) culture::french, tag::dogs, tag::men.  And I would like to place those strings inside one cell on the same row as the corresponding integers.

Answer (score 0):

This is super ugly and one day, hopefully sooner than later, i'll be able to accomplish this task in an elegant fashion though, until then, this is what got me the result I need.

#### split train_df['attribute_ids'] into their own cell/column

`helper_df = train_df['attribute_ids'].str.split(expand=True)`

#### combine train_df with the helper_df so I have the id column (they are photo id's)

`train_df2 = pd.concat([train_df, helper_df], axis=1)`

#### drop the original attribute_ids column

`train_df2.drop(columns = 'attribute_ids', inplace=True)`

#### rename the new columns

```
train_df2.rename(columns = {0:'attr1', 1:'attr2', 2:'attr3', 3:'attr4', 4:'attr5', 5:'attr6',
                           6:'attr7', 7:'attr8', 8:'attr9', 9:'attr10', 10:'attr11'})
```

#### convert the labels_df into a dictionary

```
def create_file_mapping(df):
    mapping = dict()
    for i in range(len(df)):
        name, tags = df['attribute_id_num'][i], df['attribute_name'][i]
        mapping[str(name)] = tags
    return mapping
```

#### map and replace the tag numbers with their corresponding tag names

`train_df3 = train_df2.applymap(lambda s: my_map.get(s) if s in my_map else s)`

#### create a new column of the observations tags in a list of concatenated values

```
helper1['new_col'] = helper1[helper1.columns[0:10]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)), axis = 1)
```